# What is the best way to ignore notifications of payments created manually in dashboard?

Tags: java, stripe-payments

We can create payments in Stripe in two ways:

1. With using Stripe API
2. Manually in Stripe dashboard

If I will enable notifications of payment_intent.succeeded type, then the application will be notified about all payments including payments created manually in the dashboard.

Is there any way/best practice to avoid these notifications or ignore them?

For now, I found only one solution: to put a key like "MY_CUSTOM_KEY" to the metadata when I create payment intent, and to read this key on notifications. If there no such key in notification then I ignore this notification just returning HTTP 200 without processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach of using metadata is a common and recommended approach to this problem.  Based on what you've described I can't think of a better alternative.